# get all decimal places using readxlsb and cellranger::cell_limits()

Tags: r, excel, import, tidyverse

I’m importing some messy data from a range of Excel Binary Workbooks (.xlsb) using [readxlsb](/questions/tagged/readxlsb) and `cell_limits()`, from [cellranger](/questions/tagged/cellranger). I'm struggling to get enough (all) decimal places.

This can be illustrated with the dataset that is supplied with the [readxlsb](/questions/tagged/readxlsb) package. In the example data, `TestBook.xlsb`, in sheet `Sheet3.1.1`, cell `E5`. This cell contains e^1, with a range of underlying decimal places (2,71828182845905), but is only imported with six decimal places (2.718282).

In my real life data I have text in a lot of the top lines, which convert the data to charters, like `column.4` below, where `E5` resides, and raw data with ~16 decimal places. Is there a way I can tweak the code (below) to get all the decimal places without loosing `cellranger::cell_limits()`?

```
# install.packages(c("readxlsb", "tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE) 
library(readxlsb); library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(
  read_xlsb(path = system.file("extdata", "TestBook.xlsb", package = "readxlsb"), 
            sheet = "Sheet3.1.1",range = cellranger::cell_limits())
)

# A tibble: 5 x 7
  Some       column.2 column.3 column.4   column.5 column.6 column.7
  <date>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
1 NA         "data"   ""       "2.718282" ""       ""           3.14
2 NA         ""       "in"     ""         ""       ""          NA   
3 2021-05-21 ""       ""       "a"        ""       ""          NA   
4 NA         ""       ""       ""         "third"  ""       43972   
5 NA         ""       ""       ""         ""       "sheet"     NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution could be to force column types to double when importing, i.e. `col_types = c("double")`.

Beginning by adjusting the shown digits in your tibble,

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 20)
```

Now, you get cell `E5` with all the digits from Excel.

```
library(tidyverse); library(readxlsb)
as_tibble(
  read_xlsb(path = system.file("extdata", "TestBook.xlsb", package = "readxlsb"), 
            sheet = "Sheet3.1.1",col_types = c("double"), 
            range = cellranger::cell_limits())
           )
# A tibble: 5 x 7
   Some column.2 column.3             column.4 column.5 column.6             column.7
  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>                <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>                <dbl>
1    NA       NA       NA  2.718281828459045e0       NA       NA  3.141592653589793e0
2    NA       NA       NA NA                         NA       NA NA                  
3 44337       NA       NA NA                         NA       NA NA                  
4    NA       NA       NA NA                         NA       NA  4.3972           e4
5    NA       NA       NA NA
```

According to `read_xlsb`'s [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxlsb/vignettes/read-xlsb-workbook.html) the default is set to guessed col type, from the underlying data according to:

> When implying types from the underlying spreadsheet data, the
> resultant type is the regarded as the ‘least fragile’.
>
> Effectively the order is logical – datetime – integer – double –
> string
>
> ```
> If 99 rows are of type ‘integer’ and 1 row is of type ‘double’, then all cells are regarded as ‘double’ in that column.
> If 99 rows are of type ‘date’ and 1 row is of type ‘string’, then all cells are promoted to ‘string’
> ```

A possible tweak (circumventing the auto guessed col types), cave: will treat everything as characters

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxlsb)

# read everything as character
as_tibble(
  read_xlsb(path = system.file("extdata", "TestBook.xlsb", package = "readxlsb"), 
            sheet = "Sheet3.1.1",col_types = c("character"), cellranger::cell_limits())
) ->test.char


# read everything as double
as_tibble(
  read_xlsb(path = system.file("extdata", "TestBook.xlsb", package = "readxlsb"), 
            sheet = "Sheet3.1.1",col_types = c("double"), cellranger::cell_limits())
) ->test.dbl

# make a function that checks if a string is a date
is.date <- function(x) inherits(x, 'Date')

# combine character and double, has to be adjusted according to your real data
cbind(test.char %>%
        gather(key.character,value=character),
      test.dbl %>%
        gather(key=key.numeric,value=numeric)) %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(numeric=case_when(is.date(try(as.Date(character),silent=TRUE))==TRUE ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ numeric)) %>% #set double to NA if character is date
  mutate(character=case_when(!is.na(numeric)~as.character(numeric), TRUE ~ character)) %>% #keep all remaining double
  select(key.character,character) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = key.character, values_from = character) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(Some, column.2, column.3, column.4, column.5, column.6, column.7))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>   Some       column.2 column.3 column.4        column.5 column.6 column.7       
#>   <chr>      <chr>    <chr>    <chr>           <chr>    <chr>    <chr>          
#> 1 ""         "data"   ""       "2.71828182845~ ""       ""       "3.14159265358~
#> 2 ""         ""       "in"     ""              ""       ""       ""             
#> 3 "2019-08-~ ""       ""       "a"             ""       ""       ""             
#> 4 ""         ""       ""       ""              "third"  ""       "2018-08-25"   
#> 5 ""         ""       ""       ""              ""       "sheet"  ""
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like most of my problems are solved simply by adding `col_types = c("double")` to the call in my production data. I take the default is not _double_. I will test it a bit and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: The default is a guessed col type, I added this to my answer.

Comment: You could also try the excel.link package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/excel.link/excel.link.pdf